# Get maxX and minX, maxY and minY from multiple CGRect

Tags: ios, geometry, cgrect

I got multiple child rect values. 
How can I get parent rect value from available child rect values. 
Each child rect value should be a subset of obtained parent rect.

Thanks in advance.,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you are trying to find the union of a bunch of `CGRect`s. Is this correct?

If so, then you can get the "parent" rect using something like this function:

```
static CGRect UnionOfCGRects(NSArray *rectValues)
{
    CGRect resultRect = CGRectNull;
    for (NSValue *rectValue in rectValues) {
        resultRect = CGRectUnion(resultRect, [rectValue CGRectValue]);
    }
    return resultRect;
}
```

Just pass in an array of `NSValue` objects that are instantiated with your "child" `CGRect`s.